# How to re-push as drafts to gerrit?

Tags: git, patch, gerrit

I by mistake pushed my changes into the gerrit using `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/xxxx`

Instead of `git push origin HEAD:refs/drafts/xxxx`

I want to move those changes to the drafts.

I know that we need to abandon these and then re-push the changes to the gerrit as drafts.

But I want to know is there  any command  or any other way  where I can push these changes to drafts?

Answer (score 2):

There is plugin that might be useful [WIP](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-plugins.html#wip). It doesn't change it to draft, but changes set to WIP (Work In Progress) won't show on Review Requests for the other developers.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin named force-draft which provides a ssh command that changes the status of a patchset to draft.

See more info [here](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/force-draft/+/stable-2.13/src/main/resources/Documentation).

Download the plugin [here](https://gerrit-ci.gerritforge.com/).

Comment: Thank you :) . I need that plugin to be installed in my local host or gerrit server

Comment: The Gerrit admin need to install it in the Gerrit server.